# Blu-ray burning software for OS X

Tags: osx, optical-media

I recently bought USB blu-ray (BD) writer (Samsung SE-506BB, in case that matters). OS X detects it properly, but Disk Utility.app only supports burning DVDs and CDs. Detected disk capabilities are

```
CD-Write:   -R, -RW
DVD-Write:  -R, -R DL, -RAM, -RW, +R, +R DL, +RW
BD-Write:   -R, -RE
```

I want to burn *files* to BDs - I don't care about ripping or copying disks, or burning videos in a format that is compatible with BD players. Is there such software for OS X?

Paid is ok, but obviously free would be better.

Comment: Did you try googling?
Here's an app that showed up as the first link in the search results: http://eshop.macsales.com/articles/howto-burn-bluray-toast

Comment: Yes, I did, but didn't catch that (or any other good alternative either). Also, [$80](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html) is a bit steep, as I don't need 90% of functionality it offers.

Comment: Ah! In that case my recommendation would be to use virtual windows :P (I'm not a mac user!)

Comment: I don't believe burning disks from virtual machine works properly, as it'll certainly run into buffering issues. (That's my opinion until someone tells they're doing that successfully)

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [Toast Burn](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/50438/toast-burn)([App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/toast-burn/id792619118?mt=12)), which generally works very well for burning files.  Hitherto I used Toast Titanium (Roxio was acquired recently by Corel and they have split out the product).

If you want to burn more than just files, [Toast DVD](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/50989/toast-dvd) will do the trick for that.

I'm not a real fan of Toast for the last year or so, but honestly I can't find any real viable alternatives myself at the moment as I've played with several options.